# React Router v4 not rendering component in route w/ parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am doing a project on an ecommerce site and currently have the correct routes set up for the home page at `"/"` and for the product list page at `"/:id"`. I am trying to get a route set up for a single product page however, react-router does not render my component at all.

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('root'));
  registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" render={()=> apiDataLoaded ? <HomeLayout data={data}/> : <div>Loading...</div>}/>
  <Route path="/:id" render={(props)=> <ProductListLayout {...props} />} />
</Switch>
```

Listing Component

```
return (
  <Switch>
    <div className="product-list-item-card">
      <div className="product-list-item-img" style={bgImage}></div>
      <div className="product-list-item-content">
        <div className="product-list-item-overlay">
          <Link to={`/products/${id}`}>
              <DetailsBtn />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        <h6>{brand}</h6>
        <span>${msrp}</span>
        <p>${sale}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Route path={'/products/:product_id'} render={()=> <div>Product Page</div>}/>
  </Switch>
)}
```

In the listing component above, when I clock on the link, the url is the only thing that changes? Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

**SOLVED**

Changing the order of the routes in App.js was only part of the solution. I also moved my route from the Listing component into App.js at the top of the order of the routes and now it works!

New App.js

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={`/products/:product_id`} component={ProductLayout} />
  <Route path="/:id" render={(props)=> <ProductListLayout {...props} />} />
  <Route exact path="/" render={()=> apiDataLoaded ? <HomeLayout data={data}/> : <div>Loading...</div>}/>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to change only position on your current routes...

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/:id" key={1} render={(props)=> <ProductListLayout 
   {...props} />} />
 <Route exact path="/"  key={1} render={()=> apiDataLoaded ? 
   <HomeLayout data= . 
   {data}/> : <div>Loading...</div>}/>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove switch and use div inside **ProductListLayout** component

ProductListLayout.js

```
const ProductListLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="product-list-item-card">
        <div className="product-list-item-img"></div>
        <div className="product-list-item-content">
          <div className="product-list-item-overlay">
            <Link to={`/products/${99999}`}>
              Click here
            </Link>
          </div>
          <h3>{name}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Route exact path={`/products/:product_id`} render={()=> <div>Product Page</div>}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Click here for more detail](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-4-browser-route)